# In WPF, a property should be changed by its name or by use of binding

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone

I am new to WPF and a question arose in my mind while I was developing my app.
Assume that I have a textbox defined as below

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
```

Then in my C# code, I can change the string shown in this textbox using the following command

```
MyTextBox.Text = "Hello!";
```

However, there is another way to have the same behavior by use of binding when in XAML we have

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding Content}" />
```

and in C# we have

```
public class MyText : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _content;
    public string Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set
        {
            _content = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Content"));
        }
    }
}

MyText txt = new MyText();
MyTextBox.DataContext = txt;
txt.Content = "Hello!";
```

Obviously the second option needs more coding, but the result of both of them are the same. However, in second case I do not have to care about executing the code on UI thread. So everywhere in my code when I change `txt.Content` the string in the textbox will change without any exception.

**My question is:** Is there any design issue preferences over any of these two options for changing a property?

Answer (score 3):

The second option is a prerequisite for employing MVVM pattern. 
In the first option there is no decoupling; every operation takes place in the view. 
But if you prefer the section option and apply MVVM pattern, you will have two different classes; one for implementing only UI - namely View, and one for abstracting the View and the Model.

You may refer to [this web page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what type of project you are working on.  If its a really small project, I believe you can use the direct assignment through code.  Its the quick & dirty way of doing things. But hey... If it works.. it works. :)

If you are working on a bigger project, I'm sure you will find a lot of advantages of using bindings and the MVVM pattern.  Event if you don't know MVVM you will see that using bindings will make you grow into the pattern automatically.

But hey... I believe this is a matter of opinion

Comment: Actually I have not read a lot about MVVM model, and for WPF I just started coding without reading any books about it! When I started this project, it had small code. But now it is growing and when I tried to make a separate Manager class and a Page class, I found it annoying that every time I call a method in the Page class to change something in UI, I have to run the code in `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` block. So, it just came into my mind that maybe usage of binding can be helpful to me, even for this project which has less than 1400 lines of code.

Comment: Sure give the Binding a try.  If you do things logically it will lead you into using MVVM automatically, (or at least a part of it).  Keep in mind.  Use one ViewModel class for each View (or Page) that exposes your properties, then just inject the ViewModel to the Page.  But one thing for sure, your Manager class should not directly speak to the Page.

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much covered all the pros and cons of each.  With bindings, changes to the text in the code can be automatically updated in the UI and vice versa.  As someone else said, if you want to use a view model then the 2nd option will be preferable, but unless you're required to strictly adhere to MVVM principles you can always mix and match as you see fit.  That said, it can make your code confusing to yourself and others so it's best to just pick one style and stick with it.